Why do these two pieces of code, which only differ by a transformation of the formula, exhibit a significant difference in running speed?
FunctionRange[{B + \[Pi]/6, Sin[B]/Sin[A] == 2 Sqrt[3] Sin[C1], 
  A + B + C1 == \[Pi], 
  a/Sin[A] == b/Sin[B] == c/Sin[C1], (a^2 + c^2 - b^2)/(2  a  c) == 
   Cos[B]}, {A, B, C1, a, b, c}, t]

Running this code yields quick results.

——————————————————————
However, replacing this (a^2 + c^2 - b^2)/(2  a  c) == Cos[B]with this b^2 == a^2 + c^2 - 2 a c Cos[B] in the code,The resulting code, however, continues to display "running" without producing a result. What could be the reason for this?
FunctionRange[{B + \[Pi]/6, Sin[B]/Sin[A] == 2 Sqrt[3] Sin[C1], 
  A + B + C1 == \[Pi], a/Sin[A] == b/Sin[B] == c/Sin[C1], 
  b^2 == a^2 + c^2 - 2 a c Cos[B]}, {A, B, C1, a, b, c}, t]



This could be a bug or by design, as it depends on the order of the xvars and yvars. To see this, I just changed the order of the variables and now the second case finishes very fast.
This is your first case
f0 = Sin[B]/Sin[A] == 2  Sqrt[3]  Sin[C1]
f1 = A + B + C1 == π
f2 = a/Sin[A] == b/Sin[B] == c/Sin[C1]
f3 = (a^2 + c^2 - b^2)/(2   a   c) == Cos[B]
vars = {A, B, C1, a, b, c}
Timing@FunctionRange[{B + π/6, f0, f1, f2, f3}, vars, t]


This is your second case. Notice the vars list order now is different. Changed from {A, B, C1, a, b, c} to {a, b, c, A, B, C1} and that all is needed to make it go very fast. i.e. put lower case letter before the Uppercase letters.
f0 = Sin[B]/Sin[A] == 2  Sqrt[3]  Sin[C1]
f1 = A + B + C1 == π
f2 = a/Sin[A] == b/Sin[B] == c/Sin[C1]
f3 = b^2 == a^2 + c^2 - 2  a  c  Cos[B]
vars = {a, b, c, A, B, C1}
Timing@FunctionRange[{B + π/6, f0, f1, f2, f3}, vars, t]


Using same vars order as the first case, the second one will either hang or take too long for me to wait for.
Maybe you should add the famous tag letter makes difference to your question?
V 14

put lower case letter before the Uppercase letters.Does this method solve and prevent all similar issues?

@csn899 I can't answer this. there are cases where sometimes Mathematica behaves different based on letters used. see the tag letter_makes_difference for example. I just guessed it could be the case here, that is all. You might want to report this to WRI so they can look at it. They would know for sure what is going on.
